# How to extrude (revolve) 2D shapes axisymmetrically?

Tags: extrude

I would like to draw a 2D shape and extrude it axisymmetrically (rotational symmetry). Is it possible?

[image]([source](http://www.intechopen.com/books/numerical-analysis-theory-and-application/a-semi-analytical-finite-element-approach-in-machine-design-of-axisymmetric-structures))

Comment: Use the screw modifier - I think this is was you mean: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28977/47

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the [*Screw Modifier*](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/screw.html) is exactly what you want.

This kind of tool is available in many 3d programs. It "screws" or "lathes" a profile around any axis that you pick. Here i've screwed but not used an AxisObject - in this case it uses the Object's own world matrix.

[image]

Here's i've picked an axis object, an empty, and rotated it. This is useful when Z,X,Y are not the desired rotation axis.

[image]