# how to create half circle surrounding in rounded column/pillar?

Tags: modeling

like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28976/how-to-model-the-rounded-outline-of-a-column) question, but my part is from the pillar body itself, how you create this rounded half circle surrounding perfect in rounded pillar?

here the pictures, [image] (picture from previous question above)

Comment: yeah you right, I didn't see the gif until finished :)
but the different is in the column profile, he create rectangle but what I need is half circle in top and bottom..
but thank, I think i can edit them manually to make half circle.. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a cylinder and inset each face (I to inset, then F6 and change to 'individual'). Then extrude inward and bevel the edges as necessary.

[image: result]

The result looks like this. The geometry may be difficult to work with if you're using a subdivision surface, in which case I would add extra loop cuts on the edges between the insets to connect horizontally.