# How to make concave disk?

Tags: modeling

(Solved) I am relatively new to blender and I am trying to make a concave disk (or really short cylinder) and I can't find any tutorials on how to do this. Could somebody please point me in the direction of a tutorial or tell me how? The shape I am trying to get is below. Thanks.

[image: concavedisk1]

[image: concavediskdiagram]
<sub>(source: [ingersolltillage.com](http://www.ingersolltillage.com/images/products/measurements/concave-plain.jpg))</sub>

Comment: related, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28976/how-to-model-the-rounded-outline-of-a-column

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a UV Sphere and delete the bottom half of it in Edit Mode. Go back into Object Mode, select the entire half-sphere and scale it only on the Z axis. (press "Z" while scaling is activated) That should give you a concave disk.

Answer (score 5):

To have a high level of control of the shape, and thickness, you can model profile of the disc and use Spin tool to create a mesh, like this:[image]

Don't forget to remove doubles at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with curves.

Add a Curve>Circle.

[image]

Then add a Curve>Bezier.

[image]

Edit the bezier curve to be the shape you need.

[image]

Exit edit mode, select the circle and make the bezier curve the bevel object.

[image]

[image]

Tofurhter refine the shape you can always go back and edit the bezier curve until you get what you need.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a UV sphere Smooth the shading. Go to edit mode and delete the vertex how much u need the sphere curve size, add solidify modifier and edge modifier for sharp edge. U can select and press to z axis if u need little flat.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use this method for now. Not too difficult. Sometimes I wish blender (an other 3D modelling programs) had a larger variety shapes.

Comment: @BenjiCollins There are addons that you can enable in the User Settings that do add a greater variety of shapes, but of course not all. But given how quick it is to create this, it's not such a big deal. (unless you're trying to be parametric / precise)